# Python data structure for managing dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I am learning Python3 by creating a script whose purpose is to deploy some artifacts on a server.
The requirement is that an artifact can have a dependency on one or more artifacts and should not be installed if his dependencies are not installed yet.

The installation order of this artifact and it's dependencies (if any) is important and it should also be done in a multi-threading / multi-processing way.

Currently my `dependencies` property is a list, but I am thinking to a `Queue` or to a linked list implementation in Python.

I've defined an Artifact class, but I am not sure which is the appropriate data structure for the dependencies collection.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

```
class Artifact:
    name: str = None
    download_path: str = None
    zip_file_path: str = None
    tar_file_path: str = None
    control_file_path: str = None
    download_urls: [str] = []
    btt_files: [str] = []
    checksum_passed: bool = False
    dependencies: [] = None

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
```

Comment: *Why* do you think there is any difference in this context between a list, a queue and a linked list? A list that contains other `Artifact` instances should work just fine

Comment: I was thinking to use a different data structure because the order to install those dependencies matters.

Comment: Python's lists maintain their order...

Comment: `download_urls: [str] = [str]` this really doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: What about thread safety? We will also want to to these deployments in parallel.

Comment: @orlp Thanks for highlighting it, can you, please, explain what it does in my example?

Comment: if you execute ```print(download_urls: [str] = [str])``` you will see that downloads_url = ```[<class 'str'>]```

Comment: @itprorh66 Got it and fixed it.

Comment: Why do you have a name attribute at the Artifact Class level as well as the Artifact instance level?  Remember all attributes defined at the Class level are defined equally for all instances of the artifact class.  Is this really what you want?

Comment: @itprorh66 I am afraid I don't follow your point, can you be more specific?

Comment: To better explain create an instance of  Artifact ```a1 = Artifact("Art-1")``` and a second instance ```a2 = Artifact("Art-2")``` Now ```print(a1.name)``` yields 'Art-1 and ```print(a2.name)``` yield 'Aret-2' and ```print(Artifact.name)``` yield None

Comment: Why would I use Artifact.name directly if the class is not instantiated? Maybe a dumb question, but I am coming from a C# background where properties are declared at class level.

Comment: see [Python Versus C++ Classes](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/other/python2/1.C.htm) for a good explanation